# Need to add custom HTTP Request Header to a JAX-RS client, using an interceptor

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

I'm using JAX-RS 1.0. The server verifies that a custom HTTP header is present before processing the request.

I would like to make this some sort of AOP-like behavior for the JAX-RS client, where it automatically adds the HTTP header to every request.

Does JAX-RS 1.0 support outbound client interceptors? I cant find any mention of it in the documentation. The alternative is I write a CXF-specific outbound interceptor... Thanks!

Comment: JAX-RS client was introduced in version 2.0: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/spericas/archive/2011/10/14/jax-rs-20-client-api?force=733. Are you sure you're using 1.0?

Comment: I'm using 1.0. But thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a @PreMatching interceptor

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import java.io.IOException;

@PreMatching
public class ContentTypeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
            throws IOException {

        requestContext.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do this with JAX-RS 1.0. I used CXF interceptors.

Comment: This is completely false. It can be done, as stated above.

Comment: @ThePaul at the time, I was limited to JAX-RS 1.0, so your statement is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Well, JAX-RS is an API, so should be able to provide your own implementation for it. How about implementing [javax.ws.rs.client.ClientFactory](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientFactory.html), and returning pre-configured `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` from `getClient()`. Should work fine as long as your class doesn't conflict from JAX-RS implementation you're using.

Comment: :( Not a good solution, this would likely introduce a lot of technical debt.